# storing input from prompt in array and displaying the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to take the the inputs from the user from a prompt, store that input in an array, and then display it. I want to take only 10 inputs from the user using `for` loop. I have already tried `do-while` as shown below.

```
var givenNames = new Array();
var pattern = /[\w\d]{1,}/ig;

do{
    var name = prompt("Enter some names. Only letters and digits are accepted!\nEntering an empty field stops asking","");
    if(name && name.match(pattern)){givenNames.push(name);}
}
while(name != "");

function displayNames(){
    if(givenNames.length > 0){
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-    weight:bold;'>Given names are:<\/span><br><br>" + givenNames.join("<br><br>");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-weight:bold;'>Nothing has been given!<\/span>";
    }
}
```

How do I replace it with a `for` loop?

Comment: So what's your question alout? Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aP4hj/6/)

use your for loop condition to check count as well as input.

```
var givenNames = new Array();
var pattern = /[\w\d]{1,}/ig;

var name;

for ( var i=0; i<10 && name != ""; i++){
    name = prompt("Enter some names. Only letters and digits are accepted!\nEntering an empty field stops asking", "");
    if (name && name.match(pattern)) {
        givenNames.push(name);
    }
} 


if (givenNames.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-    weight:bold;'>Given names are:<\/span><br><br>" + givenNames.join("<br><br>");
} else {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-weight:bold;'>Nothing has been given!<\/span>";
}
```

if you are using `do-while` use `do {...} while (++count < 10 && name != "")` and if you want `while` use `while (count++ < 10 && name != "" ) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
    var givenNames = new Array();
    var pattern = /[\w\d]{1,}/ig;


    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
var name = prompt("Enter some names. Only letters and digits are accepted!\nEntering an empty field stops asking","");
    if(name && name.match(pattern)){givenNames.push(name);}
    }

    function displayNames(){
        if(givenNames.length > 0){
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-    weight:bold;'>Given names are:<\/span><br><br>" + givenNames.join("<br><br>");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-weight:bold;'>Nothing has been given!<\/span>";
        }
    }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHPh/1/)**</kbd>